# Can I publish app on App Store with local payments method only?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am having a problem while publishing an app on the App Store, My app is focused on the Nepali Audience only so I integrated esewa and Khalti Payment gateways, My app contains digital products and now App Store Requirements says we need in-app purchase of app store itself. I am curious on how other apps are publishing apps with local payment methods only. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: [the guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments) are very clear. You must use in app purchase.

Comment: I see some apps without in app purchase too, Is there any possible solutions

Comment: Refer to the guidelines link. It explains the exceptions; some publishing apps and apps that provide one to one services

Comment: App Store policy questions are off-topic here. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: @Paulw11 Basically My app sells the online tests to exam takers like PTE, IELTS mock Tests, and its based for local students only, So in this case is it mandotary to keep the In App Purchase? Thank you in advance

Comment: I would say yes, you must use in app purchase. But my opinion doesn't matter. Apple says you must use in app purchase and they are the ones who are reviewing your app. It seems that in app purchase is available in Nepal so use that and then you don't need to worry about payment methods. Apple handles it for you. If you sell less than $US1,000,000 per annum be sure to register for the apple small business program